# c++ operator overloading with two non-class arguments (solved with proxy)

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm learning about overloading and I've got curious if i could make an overloaded operator with two non-class arguments.

For example with vector class having x and y to call

```
vector += (4.5, -2.1);
```

Thank you!

EDIT

I've managed to do that, and also expanded to take as many arguments as user create. This is how it looks like:

```
//Point.hpp
class Point
{
friend class Proxy;

private:
double *val;
int i;
int amount;

public:
Point();
Point(const int&);
void Set(const int &);
double Get(const int &);
int Amount();
Proxy operator += (const double &add);
};

class Proxy
{
private:
int &i;
Point &temp_point;

public:
Proxy operator , (const double&);
Proxy(Point2D &, int&);
};


//Point.cpp
Point::Point()
{
    this->amount = 2;
    val = new double[this->amount];
    val[0] = 0;
    val[1] = 0;
};

Point::Point(const int &amount) : amount(amount)
{
    val = new double[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        val[i] = 0;
    }
};

void Point::Set(const int &nr)
{
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Give me value of " << nr << " coordinate: ";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.sync();
        std::cin >> val[nr];

        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "Try again, not acceptable...\n";
        }
    } while (std::cin.fail());
}
double Point::Get(const int &nr)
{
    return val[nr];
}

int Point::Amount()
{
    return this->amount;
}
Proxy Point::operator += (const double &add)
{
    this->i = 0;
    this->val[i++] += add;
    return Proxy(*this, i);
}
Proxy::Proxy(Point &point, int &i) : temp_point(point), i(i)
{}
Proxy Proxy::operator , (const double &value)
{
    temp_point.val[i++] += value;
    return Proxy(temp_point, i);
}

//Source.cpp example
int main()
{
    Point example(3);

example += 4.5, -2.3, 3.0;

for (int i = 0; i < example.Amount(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << example.Get(i) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope somebody find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work, because `(4.5, -2.1)` will invoke the built-in comma operator, and simply evaluate to `-2.1`. It *would* be possible to do this:

```
vector += 4.5, -2.1;
```

This works because `,` has lower precedence than `+=`. You can overload `+=` so that it returns a proxy object, which in turn has an overloaded `,` operator that will append additional elements.

Comment: or you could just do `myVector.insert(myVector.end(), {4.5,-2.1});` Ok it's more verbose but at least it's built-in!

Comment: This would be possible *unless* you have to submit your code for review.

Comment: Thank you, that looks interesting. Could you spare a moment for an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
v & operator += (std::initializer_list<int> l)
{
    sum = std::accumulate(l.begin(), l.end(), sum);
    .....
```

You'll have to sligthly change your call to

```
vector += {1 , 2};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector of pairs, a much more readable option would be to

```
vector += std::make_pair( 4.5, -2.1 );
```

Looks less magical, which usually a good thing.